# Number of elements in an array when used in a structural pointer

Tags: c

Suppose I have a structure

```
 struct integer
 {
     int a[10000];
 };
```

And a string s..
 I make a function..

```
struct integer* convert_integer(char* stringInt)
 {
     int i=0;
     struct integer* A;
     A = (struct integer*)malloc(sizeof(struct integer));
     for (i=((strlen(stringInt))-1);i>=0;i--)
     {
         (A->a)[i]=(int)stringInt[(strlen(stringInt))-1-i] - 48;
     }
     return A;
 }
```

How do I find the number of elements in an array i.e the number of elements that have been filled in the array, so that i can print the array in reverse order(as i have converted the string to array in reverse order)..

Comment: Keep track of the number of elements you've set.

Comment: Argh... why do you have magic numbers? What is this `48` at the end of the statement in the `for` loop? If it's supposed to be ASCII `'0'`, then why don't you just say that and replace `48` with `'0'`?

Comment: You should instead fill in `A->a` starting from index 0 and working your way forward so that all of the elements are at the front of the array.  Make your for loop run from `0` to `strlen(stringInt)-1`.

Comment: @Jashaszun there is, ironically, one solid reason for using a semi-magic value (though I would use a macro-name and well-document it in-code): The *reader* may not have the same integer *value* for a char-literal as the literal written by a different platform to a file. The best example of this is a program written on an IBM OS/390 (or AS/400, pick anything that is EBCDIC-based) reading a file created on an ASCI platform (almost anything else besides EBCDIC, like a standard Linux box). It is *not* common, but it does happen. Likely not the case with this OP, however, so point taken.

Comment: It can be determined like a strlen the length of the array by setting -1 as sentinel in the last element. Or the length store to the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you keep a variable i with the position and then recalculates again to put in reverse order, something like this could do the job

```
struct integer* convert_integer(char* stringInt)
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    struct integer* A;
    A = (struct integer*)malloc(sizeof(struct integer));
    for (i=((strlen(stringInt))-1);i>=0;i--)
    {
        (A->a)[j++]=(int)stringInt[i] - '0';
    }
    /* ***********************************
     j has the number of elements, 
     also you could put another fild in the struct which indicates just that:
     struct integer
     {
        int count;
        int a[10000];
     };
     A->count = j;
    ************************************ */
    return A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either add a length field to the struct, or you could place a value in the last element of the array, like strings use 0x0. Then, to sizeof it, you would either just use the length field or read and count until you got to your special byte.